# HTTPS Elastic Beanstalk (AWS) to Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to configure my AWS elastic beanstalk instance so that my Android application may communicate with my API on elastic beanstalk via HTTPS.

I've found multiple resources online which talk about adding a CA-signed certificate to AWS, however if I'm redirecting from a DNS provider (i.e. GoDaddy), should I install my certificate there as well?

Also, do I need to package any form of key or certificate with my Android application if the server has a certificate which has been provided by a trusted source?

Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a tutorial on how to configure my AWS elastic
>   beanstalk instance so that my Android application may communicate with
>   my API on elastic beanstalk via HTTPS.

Just follow any tutorial for installing an SSL certificate on Elastic Beanstalk.

> I've found multiple resources online which talk about adding a
>   CA-signed certificate to AWS, however if I'm redirecting from a DNS
>   provider (i.e. GoDaddy), should I install my certificate there as
>   well?

I have no idea what you mean by "redirecting from a DNS provider". This shouldn't be an issue. The DNS provider isn't going to be doing SSL termination, so you don't need to (and can't) install your cert on the DNS provider.

> Also, do I need to package any form of key or certificate with my
>   Android application if the server has a certificate which has been
>   provided by a trusted source?

No